# Android 3D Surface Plot

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es

My requirement is to  create a 3d surface plot(should also display the x y z axis) from a list of data points (x y z) values.The 3d visualization should be done on ANDROID.

**My Inputs** : Currently planning on using open gl 1.0 and java. I m also considering  Adore3d , min3d and rgl package which uses open gl 1.0. Good at java ,but a novice at 3d programming.
Time Frame : 2 months

I would like to know the best way to go about it? Is opengl 1.0 good for 3d surface plotting?Any other packages/libraries that can be used with Android?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is too broad and refers to too many tasks to solicit quality responses. I suggest refactoring your question and focus on one part at a time.

Comment: Hi justnS,Thanks.I rephrased my question to a specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can plot the surface using OpenGL 1.0 or OpenGL 2.0. All you need to do is to draw the axes as lines and draw the surface as triangles. If you have your heightfield data, you would do:

```
float[][] surface;
int width, height; // 2D surface data and it's dimensions

GL.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES);
GL.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // line starting at 0, 0, 0
GL.glVertex3f(width, 0, 0); // line ending at width, 0, 0
GL.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // line starting at 0, 0, 0
GL.glVertex3f(0, 0, height); // line ending at 0, 0, height
GL.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // line starting at 0, 0, 0
GL.glVertex3f(0, 50, 0); // line ending at 0, 50, 0 (50 is maximal value in surface[])
GL.glEnd();
// display the axes

GL.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
for(int x = 1; x < width; ++ x) {
    for(int y = 1; y < height; ++ y) {
        float a = surface[x - 1][y - 1];
        float b = surface[x][y - 1];
        float c = surface[x][y];
        float d = surface[x - 1][y];
        // get four points on the surface (they form a quad)

        GL.glVertex3f(x - 1, a, y - 1);
        GL.glVertex3f(x, b, y - 1);
        GL.glVertex3f(x, c, y);
        // draw triangle abc

        GL.glVertex3f(x - 1, a, y - 1);
        GL.glVertex3f(x, c, y);
        GL.glVertex3f(x - 1, d, y);
        // draw triangle acd
    }
}
GL.glEnd();
// display the data
```

This draws simple axes and heightfield, all in white color. It should be pretty straight forward to extend it from here.

Comment: :Thanks for your help..As I am using java, I will try to convert your code and execute it.I will get back to you once I see the output.Thanks a lot. PS: (Could you please let me know if you have a java version of this code snippet?)

Comment: Well, this is java. You may need to replace "GL" by your OpenGL context variable name (provided that you are using OpenGL ES 1.0).

Comment: Thanks! With your example, I was able to generate some 2d surface plots.I am interested in generating 3d surface plots using (x,y,z) points.Would you be able to help in providing an example 3d surface generation using opengl android

Comment: You mean you have a set of 3D points and you want to display an isosurface that wraps these points?

Comment: :yes.an isosurface i guess!I want to connect a set of 3d points (length x width x height)to form a 3d surface/terrain. The color of each point is given by another parameter. I would like to connect the points of similar color displaying different regions.

Comment: ok, this is still confusing a bit. you "guess" you want an isosurface, then you want terrain. use google, see some images of isosurfaces and decide if that is what you want. or why don't you tell me what is it you are trying to achieve and what are your input data (now I know it's a set of colored points, but how did you obtain them? what does the color represent?).

Comment: :sorry for the confusion. I have a dataset with(x,y,z,intensity) values. based on the intensity range, I am setting colors to points.Right now, I am able to display the dataset points in 3d with colors depending on the intenstiy range (20-30 for red, 30-40 for blue and so on). However, I would like to connect like points to have a 3d surface kind of view. Please check the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1GeNljM0T8&feature=related   at 0.02.  (I am jus able to display the points now. Not sure how to connect similar intensity points to form regions as show in the video . Thanks.

Comment: ok, then you need to use the marching cubes algorithm (google) to create a set of isosurfaces, one surface per each color (intensity level). alternatively, you can use the unpatented marching triangles algorithm. the algorithms themselves just generate triangles, it is up to you to display them using any graphics API, e.g. OpenGL ES in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Re the second part of your question:

> Any other packages/libraries that can be used with Android?

Yes, it's now possible to draw an Android 3D Surface Plot with SciChart.

- [Link to Android Chart features page](http://scichart.com/android-chart-features)
- [Link to Android 3D Surface Plot example](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-3d-chart-example-simple-uniform-mesh/)

Lots of configurations are possible including drawing wireframe, gradient colour maps, contours and real-time updates.

[image: Android 3D Surface Plot]

*Disclosure, I'm the tech lead on the scichart team*

Comment: People ask for answers, we give them, get downvoted. There are solutions worth sharing other than just open source!